# Typescript dynamical string union

Tags: typescript

I need to dynamically intersect the string types as shown below.

```
export class Foo<K extends string> {
    addKey<L extends string>(key: L): Foo<K | L> {
        return this;
    }
    getKey(key: K) {

    }
}

const x = new Foo().addKey('a').addKey('b');

// need to constraint this to 'a' | 'b'
x.getKey('')
```

http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=13#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4DEIQDwDScoMwAdgCaZoxQCWZA5gHxwDeAUHN3ChRQWABPPABliIUpWq0GLABQBrYQC44ogJRqc+IgB91rTjxNwowGAFcoZODAAWdNAG4uPAL5vujC4KFLVOAINdg4vOE9PDgQIMho4EDgAXjgyYAB3bFx5DQA6PgFheQByFGK8gr8SgCNy1w4AegbU4GAKOwhEWJooFAZ4BycOuFLiuANi2o4QXJ8YKuLyoA

Comment: OK... what is the question?

Comment: Please note that you are describing a [union (`|`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) and not an [intersection (`&`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types).

Comment: @jcalz you are right. i checked it before and i thought it is intersection. now i see you are right

Answer (score 2):

Presumably your issue is that `new Foo()` produces an instance of `Foo<string>`, and `string` [absorbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_law) any [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) when joined via a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types).  That is, `string | "a" | "b"` is just `string`, which completely forgets all about `"a"` and `"b`".

All that needs to be done here is to pick a [default](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) value for `K` such that it represents the *absence* of any strings.  Some type which extends `string` but which has no values, so that when you join `"a"` to it in a union, you get `"a"` out.  Luckily that type exists, and it's called [`never`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never).  As a [bottom type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type), `never` extends every type including `string`, and is absorbed by every other type when you join to it with a union.  So `never | "a" | "b"` will be `"a" | "b"`.

Here goes:

```
export class Foo<K extends string = never> { // K has a default now
    addKey<L extends string>(key: L): Foo<K | L> {
        return this;
    }
    getKey(key: K) {

    }
}
```

And let's test it:

```
const x = new Foo().addKey('a').addKey('b');
x.getKey('') // error!
// ----> ~~
// Argument of type '""' is not assignable to parameter of type '"a" | "b"'.
```

Looks good to me.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4DEIQDwDScoMwAdgCaZoxQCWZA5nALxxnABuwUAfHAG8AUHFFwUFCgWABPPABliIUpWq0GjXgAoA1rIBcceQEpDOfEQA+R-sLH24UYDACuUMnBgALOmgDcImIAvoGijM7SMroGcATGgkKhcCEhQggQZDRwIKzswADu2LhaxgB0ElKyWgDkKNVlFZE1AEb1fnBCIKXhME3V9XAA9IPEUFDQAIRCw3AAtPOz-AB+S9MjAIJQjC4AtuTwEABmnjJgwHDVAESX1XC+7BDw6Gh0jGQozUjnMBBwYChQFB7UhQOBHE5nC6XFCXODWS7NG6lIA)

Comment: and just out of curiosity, i use const x = new Foo() not to define the static type, but how i would do it if i would need to define the type like const x:Foo = new Foo()? If i use x: Foo the inferring stops working.

Comment: This is a separate question, right?  Both `const x = new Foo()` and `const x: Foo = new Foo()` should do the same thing.  *But* `const x = new Foo().addKey('a')` and `const x: Foo = new Foo().addKey('a')` are different, because you're chaining.  Just like `const x = ""; const y: string=""` is different from `const x = "".length; const y: string = "".length`.  The latter is incorrect because the whole expression is of a different type than just the first part.  Not sure what your intent is, and a comment isn't a great place to explore much.

Comment: yes i understand it is different in each step of chain, but question is, if it is possible to define the type of x as Foo, because it seems that only way it works is to not define any type (this is the only case when it is inferred)

Comment: If you define it as `Foo` you are losing information, like saying `const y: unknown = ""` and then you're unable to access `y.length`.  You can define it as `const x: Foo<"a" | "b"> = new Foo().addKey('a').addKey('b');` which is cumbersome, so if I were you I'd just let the compiler infer the type.  Not sure why you think you "need to define" it as `Foo` without a [mcve] (what, specifically, doesn't work if you let the compiler infer the type), in a different question.  I think I have to be done with this comment conversation now.  Good luck to you!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to crack this egg

In general I would define a type alias for the subset of strings you want to serve as the union.

```
export class Foo<K extends string> {
    // note L extending K here, you may want to do it the other way
    addKey<L extends K>(key: L): Foo<K | L> {
        return this;
    }
    getKey(key: K) {

    }
}

type StringAlias = 'a' | 'b'
// Now all are constrained
const x = new Foo<StringAlias>().addKey('b').addKey('a');
x.getKey('a')
```